# Rate of convergence of mollified exponential on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, distribution-theory, convolution, weak-convergence

Consider the function
$$
f(t)=e^{-at}
$$
with $a>0$, $t \in [0, \infty)$ and let $\rho$ a smooth function on $[0, \infty)$ such that
$$
\int_0^\infty \rho(t)=1
$$
and let $\rho_\delta(t):= \frac{1}{\delta} \rho\left(\frac{x}{\delta}\right)$ so that
$$
\lim_{\delta \to 0} f * \rho_\delta(t)= f(t)
$$
I'm trying to obtain the rate of convergence of $(f *\rho_\delta, \phi)$, but if I explicitely write the convolution I obtain (after a change of variable)
$$
\int_0^T \phi(t) f * \rho_\delta(t)dt= \int_0^T \phi(t) \int_{-\infty}^{t/\delta} e^{-a(t-\delta \tau)} \rho(\tau) d\tau dt \lesssim \int_0^T \phi(t) \frac{e^{-at}}{a\delta} dt
$$
where I have used that $\rho_\delta$ is supported in $[0, \infty)$. As far as I can see this does not converges to $f$.
What is my mistake? Is there any way to obtain the rate of convergence of the convolution in terms of $\delta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^T \phi(t) f * \rho_\delta(t)dt
&= \int_0^T \phi(t) \int_{-\infty}^{t} e^{-a\tau} \rho_\delta(t-\tau) d\tau \,dt \\
&= \int_0^T \phi(t) \int_{-\infty}^{t} e^{-a\tau} \frac{\rho(\frac{t-\tau}{\delta})}{\delta} d\tau \,dt
\end{align}
$$

Let $u(\tau)=\frac{t-\tau}{\delta}$, then $\tau = t - \delta u$, $u(t) = 0$, $u(-\infty)=+\infty$ and $d\tau=-\delta du$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^T \phi(t) f * \rho_\delta(t)dt
&= \int_0^T \phi(t) \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-a(t-\delta u)} \rho(u)du\,dt\\
&= \int_0^T \phi(t) e^{-at}\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{a\delta u} \rho(u)du\,dt
\end{align}
$$

When $\delta \rightarrow 0$, the integral reaches
$$ \int_0^T \phi(t) e^{-at}\int_{0}^{+\infty} \rho(u)du\,dt
= \int_0^T \phi(t) e^{-at}dt$$